# How to automount usb after kiosk mode enable in raspberry Pi 4 with buster os?

Tags: usb, kiosk-mode, raspberry-pi4, debian-buster, raspbian-buster

Problem with Kiosk mode and USB access.

I have installed buster on raspberry Pi 4. And for open chromiam browser at startup, I enabled kiosk mode.

Now I have a problem that, it does not mount USB device (flash drives) at /media/pi

Any help and suggestions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Buster Lite and ran into a problem with installing usbmount. The error I got was "unable to locate package usbmount". I found the solution, and I am append my solution to this thread since this thread shows up on some search-engines pretty high up.

The solution I used was to clone the github repo from https://github.com/rbrito/usbmount/ and build it (instructions below is partially from the readme)

```
git clone https://github.com/rbrito/usbmount.git
cd usbmount
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y debhelper build-essential exfat-fuse exfat-utils
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i usbmount_0.0.24_all.deb
```

Additionally, use

```
sudo nano /etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf
```

to add exfat to the list of file-systems

save and reboot

Answer (score 0):

Raspbian Buster lite (without GUI) doesn't mount USB devices automatically out of the box.
There is a software called "usbmount" which adds this functionality.
You can install it using

```
sudo apt-get install usbmount
```

Then reboot the Pi

```
sudo reboot now
```

http://www.howtoeverything.net/linux/raspberry-pi/automount-external-hard-disks-raspberry-pi